# No jobs available in Euro Truck Simulator 2

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

For about a day now, no quick jobs or freight market jobs are available. Despite restarting the game over and over, there are still no jobs.

Anyone know how to get jobs, again?

Comment: Have you tried to change your city to see if other jobs show up ?

Comment: Are you playing multiplayer?

Comment: @Slayner, this is only in the main menu quick job directory, so changing my town won't do anything.

Comment: @LittleHelper this is occurring in multiplayer and single player mode.

Comment: @EmeraldOcyEmOci by changing tonw, or using ferry and so, your game might reload some task. By forcing the reload while playing (changing tonw or going from france to UK) you might be able to reload the event permitting to create the quick job listing. It is just and idea but might worth the shot to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try sleeping or using ferry or any other option to skip time forwards - that should regenerate jobs list.